# Where do I find the property names I can use in JPA?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa

Where is the list of the names I can use in the property elements in the persistence.xml file?

```
<property name="eclipselink." value="" />
```

and since JPA 2.0

```
<property name="javax.persistence." value="" />
```

Tried to search but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the list of the standard properties as refer from [here](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/):

**8.2.1.9 properties**

The properties element is used to specify both standard and vendor-specific properties and hints
that apply to the persistence unit and its entity manager factory configuration.
The following properties and hints defined by this specification are intended for use in both Java EE and
**Java SE environments:**

1. javax.persistence.lock.timeout — value in milliseconds for
   pessimistic lock timeout. This is a hint only.
2. javax.persistence.query.timeout — value in milliseconds for query
   timeout. This is a hint only.
3. javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-persist— groups that are
   targeted for validation upon the pre-persist event (overrides the
   default behavior).
4. javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-update— groups that are
   targeted for validation upon the pre-update event (overrides the
   default behavior).
5. javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-remove— groups that are
   targeted for validation upon the pre-remove event (overrides the
   default behavior).

**The following properties defined by this specification are intended for use in Java SE  environments.**

1. javax.persistence.jdbc.driver — fully qualified name of the driver
   class
2. javax.persistence.jdbc.url — driver-specific URL
3. javax.persistence.jdbc.user — username used by database connection
4. javax.persistence.jdbc.password — password for database connection
   validation

While vendor specific properties, you need refer to their documentation. For eclipse link, you can refer to [here](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.3/org/eclipse/persistence/config/PersistenceUnitProperties.html).

Comment: Any class that defines these properties as constants?